# Query updating a table column with the current id inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I just want to know if this is possible in MySQL.

This is my query:

```
update stock_trans_detail_copy_origa od

insert into item_stock_detail_copy_origa(item_stock_id,quantity,unit_cost)
select o.item_stock_id,a.item_stock_detail_balance,a.unit_cost from stock_trans_detail_copy_origa a 
inner join item_stock_copy_origa o on o.item_id = a.item_id and o.inv_loc_id = a.inv_loc_id

set od.item_stock_detail_id = last_insert_id();
```

While inserting new record to a specific table, I also want to update the other table with the value from the newly inserted record.

then I tried this trigger but gives an error: SQL Error (1442): Can't update table 'stock_trans_detaila' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `item_stock_detaila_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `item_stock_detaila` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

update stock_trans_detaila
set item_stock_detail_id = new.item_stock_detail_id;

END
```

and here's my code for inserting record:

```
insert into item_stock_detaila(item_stock_id,quantity,unit_cost)
select o.item_stock_id,a.item_stock_detail_balance,a.unit_cost from stock_trans_detaila a 
inner join item_stock o on o.item_id = a.item_id and o.inv_loc_id = a.inv_loc_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger is best for your approach. Try to refer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Create after trigger for insert newly inserted record to other table

### For example

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
```

Comment: yes thanks for that. I've tried it, but it gives me an error.